# Integrated terminal not allowing me to interact with C# console app while in debug mode (VSCode)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-debugger

I've followed this and the previous tutorial to a T (twice now) and I'm getting stuck at step 3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0

I start the debugger by pressing F5 and then select to the terminal tab as stated in the tutorial. I'm expecting to be able to to enter my name for the Console.ReadLine() on line 8 of the code, but instead of the terminal displaying "What is your name?" it says this:

[image: Terminal appears to have run dotnet build]

When I "press any key" on the terminal it just closes, bringing me to another terminal as if the program were not running. However, pressing the pause button on the debug control at the top reveals the program is running and is waiting at line 8 for Console.ReadLine() input.

**But I have nowhere to enter that input!**

[image]

Here is my launch.json file for reference, as you can see I do have "console: integratedTerminal" as stated by the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid as stated in the original post, I did "press any key", which results in the second to last screenshot. There is no prompt for my name. Please read more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I'm a linux noob and had installed VSCode via AUR which I guess is the unofficial version that features "OmniSharp" C# extension, not the official MS C# Extension.

In uninstalled that and re-installed the official MS build via snap which features the MS extension and it works. Note the debugger working and the terminal prompting me.

[image]

Solution was found here:

https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/5635